# How provide grant to a table in sentry

Tags: hive, hdfs, acl, impala, sentry

I have a `employee_database` and under employee_database I have tables `salary_table` and `bonus_table`. Right now `emp_role` has full access on employee_database. I would also like to give select access to `hr_role` on `bonus_table`. How can I achieve this in sentry?

```
SHOW GRANT ROLE emp_role;
1   hdfs://localns/emp      emp_role    ROLE    *   false   
2   employee_database       emp_role    ROLE    *   false

GRANT SELECT ON TABLE emp_database.bonus_table to role hr_role;

SHOW GRANT ROLE emp_role;
1   hdfs://localns/emp      emp_role    ROLE    *   false   
2   employee_database       emp_role    ROLE    *   false
```

I don't get error when I run the above grant but i don't see the grant in the list.

Comment: Why do you expect the privilege granted to **hr** role to show under **emp** role??? Just type `SHOW GRANT ROLE hr_role`.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter you put me back in track. Thank you!